# Ipv4 subdomain server not accessable from ipv6 client ios apple rejection

Tags: ios

I have a subdomain exp.yes.com having static ipv4 of my server which is using wcf web ervices. The services work fine when the client comes from ipv4 but is not accessible when the.client connects from ipv6. Can anybody help me out plz. Web services are hosted in windows server 2008.

Comment: In the app, do you access the server by ip-address or dns-name? I think Apple requires it to use dns-name.

Comment: Ya we are using dns name but its not accessable when we requst through ipv6 even from browsers